# Close ResultSet and Statement resources (datastax, no close() method)

Tags: java, cassandra, sonarqube, datastax-java-driver

## Hello World !

I'm in trouble trying to close some datastax resources (Statement, ResultSet).
Sonar is yelling at me to close those resources after i use them.

(for information after i use this myMethod() i call a *System.exit(0)*) Bu anyway, I would like to do it according to Sonar

*session.close()* is not enough since it appears to let Statement and ResultSet.

**/!\ ResultSet and Statement are from com.datastax.com.driver and these close() method doesn't exist on them. (different from java.sql)**

I think a session.getCluster.close() would do, but I don't want to close the Cluster.

**What would be the right way to close those resources properly ?**

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Statement;
public void myMethod() {

    Statement statement = session.prepare("select * from .....").bind();
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement);

    // doSomethingWithThisResultSet() ...

    session.close();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ResultSet is not "linked" to a connection or any other resource that needs closing. It's backed by an array. See: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ArrayBackedResultSet.java

credits: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/yjDP1xeYyYM

Statement contains only statement ID, so you don't need to close it too.

Comment: Thank you vovka, I must have missed this answer, don't know why. Anyway, now I have my result. (I may add for those having doubt that the original answer is from a datastax product manager, see link)

Comment: Does this mean the entire resultset is pulled into memory?

Comment: Edit: scratch that. it appears to do paging. My question is: If I execute a query and then never do anything with the resultset, when is the resultset "expired" (either by the cassandra server or the client).